# How to check if element exists in an Object?

Tags: html, ionic3, angular2-directives

How to use *ngIf to check if an element exists in an Object?

.ts file

```
this.data = ["cat", "dog"];
```

I want to check, in my html file, if cat exists in the object `this.data` or not. Can I do that with an *ngIf ?

Comment: what do you mean by not in html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function in your ts file to check if the wanted string exists in the array or not like this :

```
doesExist(animal: string): boolean {
return this.data.includes(animal);
}
```

and then call it in your html file :

```
<div *ngIf="doesExist('cat')"> [...] </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="data.includes('cat')">hello world</div>
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngFor** first to iterate every element in a loop and then use **ngIf** to check if value exist or not.

for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let element of data">
    <div *ngIf="element.cat">
     </div>
</div>
```

Another method is make seperate function for this but I think this is easy way to do.I hope it will help you.:)